# How to use html5parser in soupparser while I use lxml in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I'll write a program which will deal with much broken html. Now I meet one broken html that cause a error:

```
comment may not contain '--' or end with '-'
```

I had search this error for some time, and find a solution: replace the html5parser with the last version, but it doesn't work, maybe cause they use html5parser.fromstring, and I use soupparser.fromstring. And I must use soupparser, cause html5parser can't deal with such broken html.

I tried to read the source code and document, and find soupparser is use lxml.html as default factory. So I think if I can use html5parser as the factory, I can solve this problem. I know there is a parament  *makeelement* in fromstring, but no example.

So I want to konw:

1. How to change default factory to html5parser?
2. Or how to rewrite the Comment method in etree.pyx(It's difficult for me cause it's wrote by Cython)

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Finally I solve this problem by downgrade lxml to version 0.4.4：

```
pip install lxml=0.4.4
```

This version doesn't have this problem.

Comment: The latest version of lxml also works, `pip install lxml==4.1.0`